# PyQGIS set label size all layers

Tags: pyqgis

I would like to change the text size of all layers in a project, I have written the following code

```
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():

    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 5))
    text_format.setSize(1)

    capa = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer.name())[0]
    label = capa.labeling()
    if label:
        label_settings = label.settings()
        label_settings.setFormat(text_format)
        capa.triggerRepaint()
```

But it does not work, Label does not change size

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to expand on "does not work". It doesn't seem that you ever modify a layer inside the layer loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `if` block as follows:

```
if label:
    label_settings = label.settings()
    label_settings.setFormat(text_format)
    label.setSettings(label_settings)
    layer.setLabeling(label)
    capa.triggerRepaint()
```